# Spring Validation Exception : BindException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc

on submitting form to **addUser** controller exception occured

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcherServlet threw exception
>   org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
>   Field error in object 'userBean' on field 'email': rejected value [hello]; codes [Email.userBean.email,Email.email,Email.java.lang.String,Email]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [userBean.email,email]; arguments []; default message [email]]; default message [Not a vaild Email Address]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:111)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:75)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:156)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Controller for getting Form

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "register")
public String addUser(Model model) {
    if (!model.containsAttribute("wrongLink")) {
        System.out.println("not wrong Link");
        model.addAttribute(new UserBean());
    } else {
        System.out.println("wrong Link");
    }
    return "user/register";
}
```

Controller to post form

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "register")
public String addUser(@Valid UserBean userBean, Model model,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    System.out.println("in addUser form");
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("ERROR in user Form");
        return "user/edit";
    }
    return "redirect:/users/" + user.getDisplayName();
}
```

UserBean class

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
public class UserBean {

private Integer id;

@Email(message = "Not a vaild Email Address")
private String email;
//getter and setter
}
```

Form

```
<div id="container">
    <sf:form method="POST" modelAttribute="userBean">
            <div class="form">
                <sf:input path="email" type="text" id="email"
                    placeholder="email address" />
                <sf:errors path="email" cssClass="error" />
                <input class="send submit" type="submit" name="submit_first"
                    id="submit_first" value="" />
            </div>
    </sf:form>
</div>
```

spring.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />

<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="${smtp.host}" />
    <property name="port" value="${smtp.port}" />
    <property name="username" value="${smtp.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${smtp.password}" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <!-- Use SMTP transport protocol -->
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <!-- Use SMTP-AUTH to authenticate to SMTP server -->
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <!-- Use TLS to encrypt communication with SMTP server -->
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="alertMailMessage" class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">
    <property name="from" value="${alertMailMessage.from}" />
    <property name="to" value="${alertMailMessage.to}" />
    <property name="subject" value="${alertMailMessage.subject}" />
</bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000" />
</bean>


<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/resources/" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/properties/database.properties</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/properties/smtp.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example.model" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
        </props>

    </property>
</bean>


<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

why this exception is coming on entering invalid email rather than validation has to be performed.

Comment: yes on entering invalid email why exception is coming. Instead that bindingResult.hasErrors() should be execute. in my case control is not even entering in function

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In your controller's `addUser` method, your `BindingResult` needs to be immediately after the bean:

```
public String addUser(@Valid UserBean userBean, BindingResult bindingResult,
                      Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, its works. please tell me if we have many parameter to be injected in function then what is order of attribute. Is any specific order is mandatory.

Comment: As far as I know, it is only `BindingResult` where the order matters.  It must follow the bean that is being validated so that Spring knows where to put any validation errors.

Comment: here's a full list of available parameters (and more detail about this ordering): https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-methods

Comment: Thanks @DavidLavender, i spent the whole day figuring out the issue.. would have never guessed parameter ordering

Comment: Besides `BindingResult`, there is also the `Errors` object which also has to be declared immediately after the validated parameter.

Comment: Thanks David. After 5 years still this answer helps. :)

Comment: Worked well for me. Thanks