# Springboot Validation Exception: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult Exception

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf, hibernate-validator

I am trying to show validation errors in my form, but I am not able to implement it.
I am trying to pass null values, I get the hibernate validation message but I am not able to see form validation?

Here is my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveForm(@Valid Users users,Model model,Errors errors) {
        if(errors.hasErrors()) {
            return "registerPage";
        }
        else {
            model.addAttribute("message","Registered................");
        System.out.println("Save Users TEST------------------------------------>");
        userRepository.save(users);

        return "register-success";
        }


    }
```

Here is the exception:

> Field error in object 'users' on field 'salary': rejected value
>   [null]; codes
>   [NotNull.users.salary,NotNull.salary,NotNull.java.lang.Integer,NotNull];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [users.salary,salary]; arguments []; default message [salary]];
>   default message [must not be null] Field error in object 'users' on
>   field 'dept': rejected value []; codes
>   [Size.users.dept,Size.dept,Size.java.lang.String,Size]; arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [users.dept,dept]; arguments []; default message [dept],10,2];
>   default message [Length should be in between 2 to 10] Field error in
>   object 'users' on field 'name': rejected value []; codes
>   [Size.users.name,Size.name,Size.java.lang.String,Size]; arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [users.name,name]; arguments []; default message [name],30,2];
>   default message [Length should be in between 2 to 30]]

Here is my User Pojo:

```
public class Users implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="name")
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2,max=30,message="Length should be in between 2 to 30")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="salary")
    @NotNull
    private Integer salary;
    @Column(name="dept")
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2,max=10,message="Length should be in between 2 to 10")
    private String dept;

    ....

    }
```

Here is my html form(Using thymeleaf):

```
<h1 th:text="${message}" align="center"></h1>
<div class="container">
    <h2>Registration form</h2>
      <form class="form-horizontal" th:object="${registerCommand}" th:action="@{/rest/users/register}" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Username:</label>
             <input type="text"
                class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name"
                name="name" th:field="*{name}"> <br />
            <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}" th:field="*{name}"
                class="alert alert-danger"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dept">Department:</label>
             <input type="text"
                class="form-control" id="dept" placeholder="Enter Department"
                name="dept" th:field="*{dept}"> <br />
            <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('dept')}" th:errors="*{dept}" th:field="*{dept}"
                class="alert alert-danger"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="salary">Salary:</label> <input type="text"
                class="form-control" id="salary" placeholder="Enter salary"
                name="salary" th:field="*{salary}"> <br />
            <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('salary')}" th:errors="*{salary}" th:field="*{salary}"
                class="alert alert-danger"></p>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sucess">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Found my reason , i was not passing the correct parameters in my saveForm Controller-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveForm(@ModelAttribute("registerCommand") @Valid Users users, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model){

        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {

            return "registerPage";
        }
        else {
        userRepository.save(users);
        return "register-success";
        }
    }
```

**Note-If you are using BindingResult,it should be exactly after the bean.**

**It is only BindingResult where the order matters. It must follow the bean that is being validated so that Spring knows where to put any validation errors.**

Thanks to David Lavender's answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29075342/6547517

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend, I've spent a few hours with this shitt!!! Can't believe!!!

Comment: Welcome.Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Field 'salary' on object User may be null

Comment: I am passing null values through my form but null values shouldn't be accepted by the form.Instead it show the message like-"Length should be in between 2 to 10" below form fields.

Answer (score 0):

Check what data you are passing in user object while saving it, there might be salary value is going as null. As you have used @valid on Users , it will not take null or empty value in the input request data

Comment: I am passing the null value for name, dept, and salary through my form but form shouldn't pass null values instead it should show the message.

Comment: You need handle this exception to show error message on form. Example:@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
public ResponseEntity
  handleMethodArgumentNotValidException( MethodArgumentNotValidException error ) {
   return parseErrors(error.getBindingResult());
}